# How change an arbitrary range of values to ranged values?

Tags: excel, matlab, range

I am going to convert an array as [1 2 6 12 13 15 20 8 30 31] to range [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] in EXCEL or in MATLAB. Is there any function to do it? Is there any suggestion to convert this type of arbitrary range to definite range?

Comment: I fail to understand your question. Where do you wish to replace #1? Is it another matrix, and you want to replace all occurrences of array #1 in it with #2?

Comment: In better description: I have an array as [1 2 5 6 8 9 10], some values are missing (our assumption: The array should be in range between 1 to 10, but some values such as 3,4,7 are missing) and i am going to range array, for example, above array be: [1 2 3 4 5 6]. but important condition is: i have an array [1 1 1 1 4 4 5 3 3 6 6 6 6 8]. the range is between 1 and 8 with some missing value as 2, 7. how can i range this array such as: [1 1 1 1 2 2 4 3 3 6 6 6 6 5] or to any ranged and ordered array. Is it clear, right now? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution for MATLAB

In MATLAB, [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) can do the trick. For example:

```
A = [1 1 1 1 4 4 5 3 3 6 6 6 6 8]
[C, ia, ic] = unique(A);
```

Now `ic` holds the values that you're looking for:

```
ic = 
    1    1    1    1    3    3    4    2    2    5    5    5    5    6
```

Also, you can remap `ic` to a new order if you wish to do so. For instance, here's a new order similar to the one *you* suggested:

```
new_order = [1 3 2 4 6 5];
ic_new = new_order(ic);
```

which yields:

```
ic_new = 
    1    1    1    1    2    2    4    3    3    6    6    6    6    5
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab:

```
v = [1 2 6 12 13 15 20 8 30 31];
v_index = 1:length(v);
```